# Scalar Matrix over a field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Show that a 2x2 scalar matrix $A$ over a field has a square root. Meaning a matrix say $B$  that satisfies $B^{2}$ = $A$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.  Also, statements phrased in the imperative ("Give", "Prove") when asking for help are considered rude by many here; please consider rewriting.

Comment: When you say "show that **a** $2\times 2$ scalar matrix" do you mean *every matrix*? or just the existence of one such matrix, e.g. $\pmatrix{4 & 0 \\ 0 & 4}?$

Comment: Hm. I think the meaning of "scalar matrix" tricked me. Perhaps OP should tell me if I misunderstood the meaning of that in my answer.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, we do not understand your hint. In $\mathbb Q,$ both $2,-2$ fail to be squares.

Comment: @WillJagy: I was being dumb.

Answer (score 5):

It is not the case that, in any field and given any field element $x,$ that either $x$ or $-x$ is a square. Consider $2 \in \mathbb Q.$

However, assuming ``scalar matrix'' means [diagonal with all the same field elements on the diagonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix#Scalar_matrix), we do not need a field to write:

$$  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  0  &  x  \\
   1   &  0  
\end{array} 
  \right)  \cdot 
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  0  &  x  \\
   1   &  0  
\end{array} 
  \right)  =
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  x  &  0  \\
   0   &  x  
\end{array} 
  \right) 
  $$

There is nothing special about the number 2, as long as the dimension and the exponent match. Here is the 5 by 5 example:
$$ A \; = \;
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrrrr}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0  &  x  \\
   1   &  0  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0   &  1  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0   &  0  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0   &  0  & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{array} 
  \right) 
$$
$$ A^2 \; = \;
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrrrr}
  0 & 0 & 0 & x  &  0  \\
   0   &  0  & 0 & 0 & x \\
  1   &  0  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0   &  1  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0   &  0  & 1 & 0 & 0 
\end{array} 
  \right) 
$$
$$ A^3 \; = \;
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrrrr}
  0 & 0 & x & 0  &  0  \\
   0   &  0  & 0 & x & 0 \\
  0   &  0  & 0 & 0 & x \\
  1   &  0  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0   &  1  & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array} 
  \right) 
$$
$$ A^4 \; = \;
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrrrr}
  0 & x & 0 & 0  &  0  \\
   0   &  0  & x & 0 & 0 \\
  0   &  0  & 0 & x & 0 \\
  0   &  0  & 0 & 0 & x \\
  1   &  0  & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array} 
  \right) 
$$
$$ A^5 \; = \;
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrrrr}
  x & 0 & 0 & 0  &  0  \\
   0   &  x  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0   &  0  & x & 0 & 0 \\
  0   &  0  & 0 & x & 0 \\
  0   &  0  & 0 & 0 & x \\
\end{array} 
  \right) 
$$

Comment: Yes, perhaps in that case it would also work in any unitary ring. =) Good point. +1

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general over an arbitrary field $F$. Consider $A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} e & f \\ g & h \end{pmatrix} $. Asking for $A$ such that $A^2 = B$ is equivalent to being given $B$ and solve the system of equations
$$
a^2 + bc  = e \\\
b(a+d)  = f \\\
c(a+d)  = g \\\
d^2 + bc = h.
$$
Just consider a simple case : $f = g = 0$. Then either $a+d \neq 0$, which means $b=c=0$ and you want to solve $a^2 = e$, $d^2 = h$ ; in an arbitrary field, it is possible to choose $e$ and $h$ such that the polynomial $x^2 - e$ has no roots (i.e. there exists fields such that you can find $e$ and $h$ such that...). Choosing such $e$'s and $h$'s would lead to $a+d = 0$, which means $a = -d$, hence $a^2 = d^2$ and a solution would give $e=h$, a contradiction if you choose them distinct to begin with. So a matrix with no square root would simply be $B = \begin{pmatrix} e & 0 \\ 0 & h \end{pmatrix}$ where $x^2 - e$ and $x^2 - h$ are distinct irreducible polynomials in $F[x]$.

Example : Think of $B = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I think "scalar matrix" means a field element times the identity matrix. I did not notice the word scalar either.

Comment: @Will Jagy : Well in that case, as you mentioned, if the field lacks square roots of some elements we can exhibit a counter example. It wouldn't be that hard. Let's wait and see if we answered OP's question.

Comment: Arturo's comment settles the simplest case, but is not something I knew. Is it true that, in any field with any element $x,$ either $x$ or $-x$ is a square? No, false for the rationals.

Comment: @Will Jagy : That's not what Arturo meant. He meant that every element of a field $y$ is either of the form $$y=x^2$ or $y=-x^2$.

Comment: Not to hijack this question, but I actually don't understand what Arturo meant.  How is $2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ of either form?

Comment: I never said I agreed with Arturo. Perhaps @Arturo Madigin should shed some light on his comment?